# In Python create a circle With two mouse clicks

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, graphics

I need to use Python to create an archery target with five rings(yellow,red,blue,black,white)

It needs to get the first mouse click to select where the center ring should go.

The second mouse click will indicate somewhere on the circumference of the inner circle.

The remaining rings (red,blue,black,white) width need top be the same as the inner circles radius.

I am having trouble figuring out how take information from the second mouse click and give it to the inner circle to find it's radius.

```
from graphics import *



def main():
    win = GraphWin('Archery Target',300,300)
    center = win.getMouse()


    w = Circle(center, 100)
    w.setFill('white')
    w.draw(win)

    bl = Circle(center, 80)
    bl.setFill('black')
    bl.draw(win)

    b = Circle(center, 60)
    b.setFill('blue')
    b.draw(win)

    r = Circle(center, 40)
    r.setFill('red')
    r.draw(win)

    y = Circle(center, 20)
    y.setFill('yellow')
    y.draw(win)

    win.getMouse() # pause for click in window
    win.close()

main()
```

This code just lets you decide where the center will be placed, but has a single ring size.

[final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rLCm.png)

Comment: so you want every click after the first one to determine the size of the next circle?

Comment: If you're asking "how do I find the radius of a circle if all I know is the coordinates of its center and a point on its circumference?", it's the distance between them as determined by the Pythagorean formula.

Comment: The program only can accept two clicks, the center and the then a point on the inner circle circumference. once you get those two clicks then we need to find the radius of the inner circle. and the then all of the rest of the rings will have a width equal to the radius of the inner circle. I basically need to find out how to evaluate x in 'y=circle(center,x)' when all I have is the cords from the first and  second click.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `graphics` module you load is the one of John Zelle (found *e.g.* [here](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py)), what you need is another point

```
point = win.getMouse()
```

and then, as @Kevin suggested, the Pythagorean formula to calculate the distance between your points (needs `from math import sqrt`)

```
dx = point.getX() - center.getX()
dy = point.getY() - center.getY()
radius = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

You can then use `radius` to plot your circles.

If this doesn't solve your question, please give some more details.